# Craft 3 Multi-site with no “default” site AND where control panel login route remains intact and additional directories not necessary

Tags: localization, login, multi-site, htaccess, index

Maybe one of you can help me out? I've tried setting up a multi-language site with no "default site" as per [Craft 3 Multi-site with no "default" site](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23752/craft-3-multi-site-with-no-default-site). So far so good, except the control panel is not reachable via domain.com/admin. It's only reachable with the language ending, for example: domain.com/en/admin. I would prefer it would be reachable without the language ending. And is there any way to accomplish this without the additional language directories? It seems like a lot of repeated code. Anyone have any ideas? TIA!

Comment: Hi Shannon, this should have been covered by step 3 of the answer you linked to where the .htaccess file handles any requests outside of the sub-folders you've defined. Is it apache you are using? Are you able to post the code you have?

Comment: I copied the coded 1 to 1, except for the exact languages. If I enter domain.com/admin I always get redirected to domain.com/en.